FTP download of the latest files of the day
I need to connect to the FTP server in Python and download all the files that appeared only today from five different folders. Deleting files is not required.
I have just started to learn Python. We managed to connect and download all the files. How to do this only for today so that I don't download for yesterday and so on?
import ftplib
import os

ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftpserver.com')
ftp.login('user_ftp','ftp_pass')
ftp.cwd('/test/123')
filenames = ftp.nlst()

for filename in filenames:
    host_file = os.path.join(
        'C:\\test\\', filename
    )

    try:
        with open(host_file, 'wb') as local_file:
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, local_file.write)
    except ftplib.error_perm:
        pass

ftp.quit()


import ftplib
import os
from datetime import datetime

# Параметры FTP сервера
ftp_host = 'ftp_server'
ftp_user = 'ftp_user'
ftp_password = 'ftp_pass'

# Целевая локальная папка для сохранения файлов
local_folder = 'C:\\test'

def download_files_from_ftp(ftp_folder):
    ftp = ftplib.FTP(ftp_host)
    ftp.login(ftp_user, ftp_password)
    ftp.cwd(ftp_folder)

    files = ftp.nlst()
    today = datetime.now().date()

    for file in files:
        file_time = datetime.strptime(ftp.sendcmd('MDTM ' + file)[4:], "%Y%m%d%H%M%S").date()
        if file_time == today:
            local_filename = os.path.join(local_folder, file)
            with open(local_filename, 'wb') as local_file:
                ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + file, local_file.write)

    ftp.quit()

# Список папок для загрузки файлов
ftp_folders = ['folder1','folder2','folder3']

# Загрузка файлов из каждой папки
for folder in ftp_folders:
    download_files_from_ftp(folder)


Stack Overflow is an English language site, please translate your code comments to English. Thanks.

While working, this is general pretty inefficient solution. For better options, see Download only yesterday's file with FTP in Python.
